# Python strings shifting along and inserting a character

Tags: python, string

If I have a stream of individual characters in python and I want a string buffer 4 characters long, how can I have it so that the newest character goes to the end of the buffer and the other characters all shift down by one.

I have a stream of characters being fed from a serial port and decoded into a variable called `decoded` each run of the loop there is only one character read from the `ser.read()`. I wish to end the loop when a certain string is received. To do this I want to be able to put the characters into a buffer that I can check.

E.g.

decode each run of the loop will be

```
H

e

l

l

o
```

---

```
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM1')

PBIT = True
while PBIT
    read = ser.read()
    decoded = read.decode('utf-8')
```

Going into a variable called Buffer.

```
"    "

"   H"

"  He"

" Hel"

"Hell"

"ello"
```

Comment: How does adding the serial part make your question any clearer?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't. I was just trying to make it more obvious that the decode is only getting 1 character at a time. Sorry. I'll give the deque thing a try.

Comment: I see. No no, no need for apologies. Just had to be sure. The *for* loop also gives you a character at a time.

Answer (score 8):

You could create the buffer using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (double ended queue) of fixed length:

```
from collections import deque

size = 4
decode = "Hello"
buffer = deque(' '*size, maxlen=size)

for x in decode: # simulates characters coming from a stream
    buffer.append(x)
    print(''.join(buffer))
```

Once the deque is full, an item is discarded from the opposite end to accommodate the new entry.

---

```
   H
  He
 Hel
Hell
ello
```